# keras import assertion error in new virtual env

Tags: python, keras

After installing the newest Keras and TF in a virtual env on a Win10 machine I keep having an assertion error

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-88d96843a926> in <module>()
----> 1 import keras

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\aind-vui\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import activations
      4 from . import applications
      5 from . import backend

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\aind-vui\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py in <module>()
      2 import six
      3 import warnings
----> 4 from . import backend as K
      5 from .utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
      6 from .engine import Layer

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\aind-vui\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>()
     69 if 'KERAS_BACKEND' in os.environ:
     70     _backend = os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']
---> 71     assert _backend in {'theano', 'tensorflow', 'cntk'}
     72     _BACKEND = _backend
     73 

AssertionError:
```

tensorflow itself imports fine. I also have keras working perfectly fine in my main working env and the keras.json is properly pointing to tensorflow.

pip list shows that Keras is installed in the env.

```
python -c "from keras import backend"
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

shows the proper message.

frustratingly

```
$ python
>>> import keras
>>> quit()
```

works, but doing the same thing in a jupyternotebook does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
$ export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
```

and re-run your program.
Apparently you defined it, but chose something outside of those 3 values.

Comment: That did, thanks so much. Just for information of others trying this on Windows, the windows version of export is set
so
> set KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow

Comment: Thanks! Helped. In particular on an Amazon AWS.